# How to access hosts in my network from microk8s deployment pods

Tags: linux, kubernetes, networking, microk8s

I am trying to access a host that sits in another server (but on my network) from inside the pod of deployment and I am using `microk8s`.

The thing is that on the server where I have `microk8s` installed I can easily ping it by `ping my-network-host.qa.local`. But when I go inside the pod with `microk8s kubectl exec -it pod_name -- /bin/bash` and I do `ping my-network-host.qa.local` it says: `Name or service not known`.

And when I connect to a VPN on my computer to be on that network and I deploy it locally using `docker-desktop kubernetes` I can ping that host from within the pod. So I think the problem sits in `microk8s` which is not letting my pod use my network.

Is there any way to tell microk8s to use my hosts from my network?

p.s. I can ping the `ip` of that server from the pod, but I am not being able to ping the host from the pod

Answer (score 3):

Based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62678275/11338984) that I found on StackOverflow, i managed to fixed it.

There were 2 changes needed to make it work:

Update **kubelet configuration** to use `resolv-conf`:

```
sudo echo "--resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf" >> /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubelet
```

Restart kubelet service:

```
sudo service snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet restart
```

Then change the **CoreDNS forward** to point to your nameserver:

First open coredns config map so you can edit it

```
sudo microk8s.kubectl edit configmap coredns -n kube-system
```

and update the file at

```
forward . 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 #REMOVE THIS LINE
forward . xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #ADD THIS WITH YOUR IP
```

You can get eth0 DNS address:

```
nmcli dev show 2>/dev/null | grep DNS | sed 's/^.*:\s*//'
```

On my case I already had the ip as nameserver on `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.

Now just save the changes, and go inside your pods so you will be able to access them.

There is a comment in another post that suggest adding

```
forward . /etc/resolv.conf
```

But that didnt work on my case.