# How to access a machine in my network from microk8s deployments

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I have some pods running in microk8s and they need to access a machine outside the cluster and inside my local network. The problem is they can't access it even using the IP address.

Example:

- In the host itself I can use "curl " and get the expected result, but inside a pod I can't do that.

I just did a very simple test using minikube and the IP is accessible by default, so I think the issue is something related to microk8s and I prefer to use it if possible.

Addons enabled:
dashboard
dns
ha-cluster
istio
metrics-server
registry
storage

This question is similar to this one [How to access hosts in my network from microk8s deployment pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66759153/how-to-access-hosts-in-my-network-from-microk8s-deployment-pods) but in my case I can't even access using the IP, so it's not a problem of naming resolution like it was there.

Is there anything else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: What response do you get from the `ping` command ?
Doesn't the `pods-network-cidr` overlap with the IP range of your VMs ?
Are you using Calico CNI ?

Comment: @matt_j, It gets stuck in the first line. From the host machine it gets packages in less than 1ms. Ping to a internet site works as expected. The cidr from the pods is the same as the IP I'm trying to access. 

IP from the pod: 10.1.0.67
IP I'm trying to access: 10.1.0.21

The calico pod is up and running the kube-system.

It took me a long time to respond because this is supposed to be a test enviroment (currently only using docker) and I was dealing of other things in the company. The production enviroment was deployed to AWS EKS without problems. 

I